# How to specify the websocket connect timer in CPPRest SDK

Tags: c++, websocket, cpprest-sdk

I'm trying to connect an websocket server with CPPRest SDK.
But as per their [documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/classweb_1_1websockets_1_1client_1_1websocket__client__config.html) there is no `timeout` in `websocket_client_config` compared to [http_client_config](https://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/classweb_1_1http_1_1client_1_1http__client__config.html).

So how do I correctly specify the timeout so that the `connect` `pplx::task` will exit after the mentioned timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Actually CPPRest SDK seems to be abandoned. The websocket part was changed last time 3 years ago. Don't use in new projects. Consider using Boost.Beast or WebSocket++ by Zaphoyd.

Comment: But can I cancel it after some timeout since the websocket connect is a `pplx::task`?

Comment: Only tasks which were created with cancellation token can be cancelled. That is no your case as you can see in sources here: https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk/blob/9c654889efb6f5bda69fe8f52b3f7d3d3fb56cd8/Release/src/websockets/client/ws_client_wspp.cpp#L450

So the answer is no.

P.S.: Actually as I can see Microsoft just took Zaphoyd websocket++ implementation and made just are pretty bad wrapper around it. LOL.